# add css to jquery 'flux' animation

Tags: jquery, css, flux

I'm currently creating an image slideshow using the JQuery plugin 'Flux'. I want to add some css to the images to make them the same height and have rounded corners, however, I cannot apply CSS to them.

I use the Concentric transition (demo here: http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/).

My html code looks like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img class="test" src="img/image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="test" src="img/image2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

I've tried both id and class for 'test' and used all these css-methods

```
#slider .test
#slider img.test
#slider img#test
#slider #test
#test
.test
```

None seem to work, anyone has a fix?

See for yourself: jsfiddle.net/6gTnf/1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
img
{
height:100px !important;
border-radius:10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#slider img.test{
height:100px !important;
border-radius:10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Eh.. What is a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ , you can post dummy code in here. So we can easily find a solution for your problem.

Comment: I can't seem to get my code working. http://jsfiddle.net/6gTnf/
CSS is applied though (probably because the jquery is not)

Comment: Did you try by writing  a inline style ?

Comment: I updated it, it's the same as on my webpage now. Can you edit it too to test your solutions?

Comment: Forgot the link: jsfiddle.net/6gTnf/1

Comment: https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider did check the doc. ? I think it will help.

Comment: I did, didn't help me out.